# Doctrine postLoad event for associations

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm

I currently have an entity which I would like to modify slightly upon load. This modification will be a one time change which will then be persisted in a new field along with the entity.

To clarify my current objective: The entity is a "Location" and forms part of a nested set. It has a name, lft/rgt values and an Id. One computationally expensive task I was performing with this entity was to fetch a full location path and display it as text. For example, with the location entity "Waterloo" I want to display as "Waterloo|London|United Kingdom". This involves traversing through the entire set (to the root node).

To reduce the cost of this I've created a new field on the Location entity that can be stamped with this value (and updated as/when the location (or any location within the tree) name is modified). Considering my application is in a live state I need to avoid running this as a one off process as it would incur quite an intensive one-time hit on the DB, instead I'd like to apply this update as and when each location (without that value) is loaded. I assumed  Doctrine's postLoad event mechanism would be perfect for achieving this, however..

The Location entities are not loaded directly by my application, they will always be the inverse side of a relation. With this is mind, and the fact that doctrine's postLoad event:

- Doesn't load (allow access to) any associated data
- Is only fired for owning Entities

I have no way of gently making these modifications.

Anyone have any advice, or experience on this?

Comment: As a personal advice, I wouldn't handle this via fancy logic in the persistence layer. Instead, build an aggregate model that proxies calls to your entity and eventually handles getting the parent items. This would fit your service layer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was able to load the associated Location objects within the postLoad event by using the initializeObject() method on the Entity Manager.

```
/**
 * Upon loading the object, if the location text isn't set, set it
 * @param \Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs $args
 */
public function postLoad(\Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    $this->em = $args->getEntityManager();
    $entity = $args->getEntity();

    if ($entity instanceof \Entities\Location)
    {
        if (is_null($entity->getPathText()))
        {
            $entity->setPathText("new value");
            $this->em->flush($entity);
        }
    } elseif ($entity instanceof {parent Entity})
    {
        $location = $entity->getLocation();
        // This triggers the postLoad event again, but this time with Location as the parent Entity
        $this->em->initializeObject($location);
    }
}
```