# Loading Doctrine entities in postLoad

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have an entity which implements a postLoad lifecycle event method. This method conditionally updates the entity and attempts to save it. Something along the lines of:

```
/** 
 * @PostLoad 
 */
public function checkExpiryDate()
{
    $currentDate = new App_Date();

    // Check the expiry date here
    if ($currentDate->getTimestamp() > $this->getDateExpired()->getTimestamp()) {
        $this->Status = "expired";
        $this->ServiceLayer->saveEntity($this);
    }
}
```

However, I'm receiving the following error:

```
Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in Doctrine/ORM/Internal/Hydration/ObjectHydrator.php on line 149
```

It seems I'm unable to save an entity during postLoad.

I stumbled across [this ticket](http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-1010) which suggests registering the ObjectHydrator under a new key and specifying the hydrator during any new queries.

However, I'm wondering if there is a nice way to implement this at a more abstract level; I would like to automatically register a new ObjectHydrator whenever a query is built during a postLoad dispatch.

Additionally could anyone briefly explain why this is an issue in the first place? From what I can see the query is being removed once the hydrator has been used, but I don't see why this would be a problem when a new query is built, even if the hydrator is reused.

Thanks for any pointers!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is unsupported, especially if you are calling `EntityManager` operations inside your service layer.

You would run into every possible weird race condition because you are basically re-using the same hydrators and destroying their internal state, rendering them useless while they are still hydrating your resultset.

This is a known issue, which has workarounds if you really need to handle this initialization logic during `@PostLoad`. See http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-1010

Instead of using a listener to populate missing dependencies of your object, consider using your service layer to handle that after you fetch the object from the entity manager. This anyway will disallow you from having any proxies for the entity in your example.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up with me. I hadn't actually considered the implication on my Proxies. I'll follow your advice and, rather than switching out the hydrator during, fire my own event after the fetch to manage checks like this.

Comment: The fact that the issue has been closed http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-1010 does that mean its now possible to do saves with the entitymanager in a postLoad event or is this just a really bad idea. I have business rules firing on postLoad and if an entity is in a particular state I want to add an item to one of its collections and persist that. In actual fact this works but when I use the http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer I get an exception "Can't pop from an empty datastructure".

Comment: I also found this post which is semi related so adding it here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14500954/doctrine-postload-event-for-associations