# Doctrine 2, trigger event after EAGER fetch

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Multiple entities in my application have a gallery associated, defined this way

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Gallery")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="gallery_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $gallery;
```

I like to perform some custom logic when those entities are loaded, using **postLoad** doctrine event. I eventually learnt that Doctrine doesn't advice to play with associations on postLoad event, as they are not fully loaded...

In order to improve performance, I added a **fetch="EAGER"** on this association. Which is nice to reduce the number of requests while fetching a collection.

But now the getGallery() is empty in the postLoad event.

Is there any way to trigger something after the associations have been performed ? I could wrap a service and/or model around my entity to do the logic but I would prefer a simple event.

Thanks !

Comment: Have you searched SO? maybe [this question can help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14500954/doctrine-postload-event-for-associations)

Comment: Yes I tried this but didn't work. This workaround still effective in current Doctrine version ?

Comment: It's tagged `Doctrine2` so i'm guessing it's still valid. What is it you want to do with the related entity? maybe it's an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?