# Doctrine PostLoad Lifecycle Callback not executed in fetchJoin

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a problem with a [Lifecycle Callback of Doctrine ORM](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#lifecycle-callbacks), that is not executed on fetch-joined entities, while it's regularly executed on entities that are lazy-loaded.

This is the code:

**EntityA:**

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity\EntityA;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * EntityA
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class EntityA {
    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="EntityB", mappedBy="EntityA", indexBy="name", cascade="all", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $entitiesB;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
     */
    private $myNotMappedField;

    public function __construct() {
        /*initializes here fields mapped by Doctrine to db*/
        $this->name='';

        $this->initNotMappedFields();
    }

    /**
     * Here I initialize properties not handled by Doctrine
     * @ORM\PostLoad()
     */
    public function initNotMappedFields() {
        $this->myNotMappedField=new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

**EntityB:**

```
/**
 * EntityB

 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()

 */
class EntityB {
    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $name;


    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="EntityA", inversedBy="entitiesB")
     */
    private $entityA


    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
     */
    private $myNotMappedField;

    public function __construct() {
        /*initializes here fields mapped by Doctrine to db*/
        $this->name='';

        $this->initNotMappedFields();
    }

    /**
     * Here I initialize properties not handled by Doctrine
     * @ORM\PostLoad()
     */
    public function initNotMappedFields() {
        $this->myNotMappedField=new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
// this works right:
// EntityA::initNotMappedFields() is properly called
$entityA = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('AppBundle:EntityA')->findOneById(1); 
// EntityB::initNotMappedFields() is properly called
$entityA->getEntitiesB();

// I want to fetch join EntityB into EntityA, to avoid
// multiple single SQL statements to be executed against the DB
// EntityA::initNotMappedFields() is called
$entityA = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('AppBundle:EntityA')->createQueryBuilder('entA')
    ->addSelect(['entB'])
    ->andWhere('entA=:id')->setParameter('id', $id)
    ->leftJoin('entA.entitiesB', 'entB')
    ->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult();

// EntityB::initNotMappedFields() is NOT called
$entityA->getEntitiesB();
```

What am I missing?

Comment: shouldn't you be actually running a void process  ? you are only creating an object.

Comment: @Confidence I'm not creating a new object, I'm fetching it from DB and for that case the __construct() is not executed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is 'Yes, Any load operation triggers postLoad events'.

https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/6568

For those in the future arriving here from Google, the problem was in my application, I was using in PostLoad of the root entity some informations setted in the PostLoad of the fetchjoined entities, but certainly no one can guarantee me that one PostLoad is executed before or after some other PostLoad.

They will be executed, soon or after.

So the approach to use is that described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/45216602/7135824

Comment: That makes a lot of sense.  So just to clarify, the `postLoad()` command *was* ran for those associated entities?

Comment: yes it was. I didn't noticed that because I got an Exception caused by one of the uninitialized fields, so I thought the problem were that the postLoad was not fired; instead it would be fired simply after the execution of the postLoad in the root entity (which caused the Exception). Removed the exception, all postLoad were executed.

Comment: Great, thank you for the clarification!  I wish the Doctrine documentation was a little more explicit with this.

Answer (score 1):

This occurs because the first example is going to generate a SQL query to get each individual **EntityB** and then load it into **EntityA**.  If A has 10 Bs, you'll get 10 additional queries to get each B which call your `postLoad()` callback on B, because the EntityManager is the one constructing **EntityB**.  See the [documentation on the **postLoad()** event](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#postload).

What I would do is simply use **EntityA** to call your initialization on **EntityB**:

```
/**
 * Here I initialize properties not handled by Doctrine
 * @ORM\PostLoad()
 */
public function initNotMappedFields()
{
    $this->myNotMappedField = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();

    // the 'if' here is in case you load EntityA without joining EntityB
    // so that you won't cause the extra queries if you don't want EntityB in there
    if ($this->entitiesB) {
        foreach ($this->entitiesB as $entityB) {
            $entityB->initNotMappedFields();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is the method I implemented as a workaround to resolve the problem, but it's ugly because I have to iterate in each field of entityA (and the same in entityB because I have some self referenced oneToMany in that class) and according to the doc the postLoad  should be triggered even for fetch joined entities... The doc says "This event is called after an entity is constructed by the EntityManager", and  in my case that entities are constructed by em, not by me (i.e. instanced with `new`). Maybe it's a bug to report?

Comment: I'm not sure. One of the core developers of Doctrine commented a few years ago on a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14500954/doctrine-postload-event-for-associations and did not offer up that Doctrine was capable of doing this, and suggested another method instead.

Comment: Also, this post said behavior changed in Doctrine 2.5: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/changelog/migration_2_5.html#events-postload-now-triggered-after-associations-are-loaded but that also doesn't necessarily mean it'll work in your case.  It just means that the first `postLoad()` will happen after the associations are loaded.  So all it really means is that Doctrine 2.5 will make my posted workaround safe. What version of Doctrine are you on?

Comment: I'm using 2.5 and yes, your workaround should be safe thanks to the new feature you linked. Thanks for your time.